# What is the relationship between the standardized multiple regression coefficient & the semi partial correlation for models with k>2 predictors?

Tags: multiple-regression, standardization, partial-correlation

I have found myself Googling this question more than once:  ¿What is the relationship between the standardized multiple regression coefficient (the standardized partial slope) and the corresponding semi-partial correlation (also called the part correlation by some)?  The answers that I find are not helpful, because they always provide an answer restricted to a multiple regression model with at most 2 predictors.

Note:  The following similar question ([Multiple regression or partial correlation coefficient? And relations between the two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/multiple-regression-or-partial-correlation-coefficient-and-relations-between-th)) addresses partial correlations and this question ([Is there a difference between semipartial correlation and regression coefficient in multiple regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112891/is-there-a-difference-between-semipartial-correlation-and-regression-coefficient)) focuses only on the trivariate model (as indicated above).

So, I will start here with a summary of the two straightforward models.

For **bivariate regression**
$$y=\alpha + \beta· x + \epsilon$$
the standardized slope, $\beta^*$, equals the correlation between $x$ and $y$:
$$\beta^* = r_{x,y}$$

For **trivariate regression**
$$y = \alpha + \beta·x + \gamma·z + \epsilon$$
the standardized partial slope for $x$ can be written as
$$\beta^* = \frac{r_{y,x} - r_{y,z}·r_{x,z}}{1-r_{x,z}^2}.$$
When taken with the fact that the semi-partial correlation $r_{y(x|z)}$ is given by the equation
$$r_{y(x|z)} = \frac{r_{y,x} - r_{y,z}·r_{x,z}}{\sqrt{1-r_{x,z}^2}}$$
we can obtain the following relationship between the standardized slope and the semi-partial correlation
$$\beta^* = \frac{r_{y(x|z)}}{\sqrt{1-r_{x,z}^2}}$$

For **multiple regression models with 3 or more predictors**
$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 · x_1 + \beta_2 · x_2 + \cdots + \beta_k · x_k + \epsilon$$
where $k>2$. My question is whether the following formulation is correct for multiple regression models with 3 or more predictors:
$$\beta_i^* = \frac{r_{y(i|\langle i\rangle)}}{\sqrt{1-R_{i,\langle i\rangle}^2}}$$
where $r_{y(i|\langle i\rangle)}$ is the semi-partial correlation for y with i partialling out all other variables but the $i$-th, and $R_{i,\langle i\rangle}^2$ is the coefficient of determination obtained from predicting the $i$-th predictor from all of the other predictors in the model. (The notation $\langle i\rangle$ indicates the set of all predictor variables but the $i$-th.)

I am fairly confident my answer is correct, but I have not located a website to confirm this. So, my questions are: (1) ¿Is this correct? (2) ¿Can someone provide a proof? or (3) ¿Can someone provide easily accessible references?

Comment: It's been a while since you've asked this question: have you been able to locate an answer in the meantime?

Comment: I have been playing with a couple of numerical examples, and your formula appears to be correct.

Comment: I have not located any more information, and I haven't had the time to work out the math either...but I have been operating under the assumption that my rationale is correct.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](https://doi.org/10.5243/jsswr.2013.24) lists an indirect way to convert between standardised $\beta$'s and partial and semi-partial coefficients via the $t$-statistic.

To wit, in a regression with $n$ samples and $p$ predictors, the partial-correlation coefficient of a predictor $X_f$ is given by
$$
r_{\text{par}} = \frac{t_f}{\sqrt{t_f^2 + \text{df}}}\ ,
$$
where $t_f$ is the $t$-statistic of the regression coefficient $\beta_f$, and $\text{df}=n-p-1$. On the other hand, the semi-partial correlation coefficient is given by
$$
r_{\text{s-par}} = \frac{t_f\sqrt{1-R^2}}{\sqrt{\text{df}}}\ ,
$$
where $R^2$ is for the full model, and the rest of the notation is as above.