# Is it possible to identify an IV whose effect on DV is being strengthen by a suppressor?

Tags: multiple-regression, suppressor

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244964/could-a-predictor-with-a-zero-correlation-to-a-response-be-significant-in-a-mult). Suppose we have a multiple regression and we can identify suppressor IV (by looking at the correlation between IV and DV and t-stat of IV in the regression). Is there a way to detect which IV or a collection of IVs is being amplified by the suppressor?