# Is it possible that two independent variables were insignificant when present alone in the model, but when together in the model become significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, modeling, multicollinearity

I did learn about collinearity issue where it is possible that 2 significant independent variables when used together in the model can make either or both insignificant. However does the vice-versa case exist? and under which circumstances?

Comment: +1 first, i think the answer is yes, but i am struggling to give you a numerical example.

Comment: See this thread, especially about "suppressor variables".  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73869/suppression-effect-in-regression-definition-and-visual-explanation-depiction

Comment: Although it's unclear what the "vice-versa" case might be, we have [many posts explaining how significance can change as variables are introduced in regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+significant+not+score%3A40) -- and they cover all the possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

In general and dismissing collinearity , linear models become more representative as variables are introduced even though R^2 is relatively low in business application. Literature exists explaining this rational. During data exploratory practice one may find two less significant variables resulting in higher significance when clustered (unsupervised data mining ).

Comment: This answer is here is lacking and unclear. It may behoove the OP and other readers here to provide a more thorough explanation. Otherwise this answer may be deleted for being low quality.