# If I remove a variable from a regression, does the change in R squared reflect the amount of R squared contributed by that variable?

Tags: regression, r-squared

In Stata, I am performing the following regression on a data set

```
regress sales price female black income hs age
```

This yielded

> R-squared: .3208
>
> Adjusted R-Squared: .2282

So let's now suppose I drop the variable `age`.

```
regress sales price female black income hs
```

This yielded

> R-squared: .1661
>
> Adjusted R-Squared: .0936

Thus, incorporating the variable `age` in the regression significantly changes R squared and adjusted R squared.

## My Question

If I remove a variable from a regression, does the change in R squared reflect the amount of R squared contributed by that variable?

Comment: Could you tell us what "contributed by" means to you?  In some reasonable senses the answer is clear *yes* whereas in other senses it is *no*.

Comment: I think I took it to mean what Jake Westfall said in his answer. However, I wondered if there were other possible meanings besides additivity. I left it open ended in the hopes that someone might reply with a different interpretation besides additivity since its not very interesting. Rarely is it the case that all my variables would be uncorrelated.

Comment: One standard meaning is that the change in r-squared for a given regressor $X$ reflects (in the usual least-squares linear-relationship sense) additional information about the response *that is not already accounted for* in all the other regressors.  That obviously depends on the other regressors (except when all of them are orthogonal to $X$).  In any case, despite what @Jake writes, that there is no requirement that all the other regressors be mutually orthogonal: that's irrelevant.

Comment: @whuber To make sure I understand, you're saying that what's relevant for a given predictor $X$ is whether $X$ is orthogonal to the subspace spanned by the other predictors, but whether those other predictors are orthogonal amongst themselves is irrelevant, right?

Comment: That's exactly right, @Jake.

Comment: @whuber It's true of course, but I'm not sure I see how it contradicts my answer? (Or maybe you're not claiming that it contradicts my answer?) We can only get the additive decomposition of the total $R^2$ as the sum of all the partial $R^2$ values if the condition that you mentioned holds for every $X$ -- but if that condition holds for every $X$, this implies that all of the predictors are uncorrelated, yes?

Comment: There is no contradiction to your answer, @Jake, but what you write in your answer isn't relevant to the question.  The question does not concern decomposing $R^2$ additively for *all* variables: it concerns only the effect of *one specified variable* ("that variable").

Comment: @whuber Ah, I see

Answer (score 5):

Only if all of the predictors in the model are completely uncorrelated.

In that ideal case it is possible to neatly decompose the total $R^2$ into a set of partial $R^2$ values for each predictor, such that the partial $R^2$ values all add up to exactly the total $R^2$. However, if there are any correlations among the predictors, then the partial $R^2$ values generally won't add up nicely to the total $R^2$. They could add up to more than the total $R^2$ or less than the total $R^2$ -- this latter case would indicate a pattern of [suppression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73869/suppression-effect-in-regression-definition-and-visual-explanation-depiction) among the predictors.

Comment: Thanks very much. This was very clear. Just to clarify, this applies to both $R^2$ and the adjusted $R^2$?

Comment: @StanShunpike No, this all applies to the classical, un-adjusted $R^2$. I'm not positive, but I *think* that the adjusted $R^2$ values will not generally add up nicely even when all the predictors are uncorrelated (although it should of course be pretty close as long as the sample size is not tiny).