# Linear regression coefficient's increase meaning

Tags: regression

I have run a series of linear regression models. In model 1, I have added three covariates. Model 2 is the same as model 1 with an extra covariate (education) added to examine the effect of education on the coefficient of the outcome variable.

When comparing model 1 to model 2, if the coefficient for the outcome variable decreases from model 1 to model 2 I can say that the extra education variable I added in model 2 has attenuated the outcome variable. I get that.

However, in some instances the coefficient for the outcome variable **increases** from model 1 to model 2 - how do i interpret this (it's not attenuating the outcome variable, it has strengthened the coefficient but what does that mean?). I have put an example below.

**Example**

Group 1 - model 1 coefficent = 4.70. Model 2 coefficient = 4.23 in model 2 (i.e. a decrease from model 1)

Group 1 - model 1 coefficent = 4.16. Model 2 coefficient = 5.32 in model 2 (i.e. an increase from model 1)

Comment: Perhaps this Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73869/suppression-effect-in-regression-definition-and-visual-explanation-depiction might help you.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a **moderator** on your hands. See [this blog post](https://significantlystatistical.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/confounders-mediators-moderators-and-covariates/) for information.
To better understand what this means, think of this second variable as masking some of the actual relationship between the original coefficient and your response variable. Lets try a simple example:

Suppose we have a simple dataset of data trying to explain happiness (presume an index of 0-100) by measuring the amount of friends and country of origin (0=Japan, 1=China).

```
moderator <- data.frame(friends=c(3,3,4,5,7,7,7,8,9,9), happy = c(20,30,50,35,70,20,40,50,50,70), country = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))
moderator$country <- factor(moderator$country, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Japan", "China"))
```

Now we will fit a model with just friends and with both friends and country:

```
Call:
lm(formula = happy ~ friends, data = moderator)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   15.105     14.697   1.028   0.3341  
friends        4.580      2.236   2.048   0.0747 .
```

And

```
Call:
lm(formula = happy ~ friends + country, data = moderator)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   -9.079     13.541  -0.670  0.52406   
friends       11.382      2.861   3.978  0.00534 **
country      -35.974     12.484  -2.881  0.02360 *
```

Here too one can see that the coefficient for friends has increased significantly after controlling for country. This makes theoretical sense to call country a moderator. But this isn't very clear yet. so let us do something that is often overlooked - lets plot it (using the `ggplot2` package):

```
p.1 <- ggplot(moderator, aes(x = friends, y = happy)) + 
    geom_point(size = 5) + geom_smooth(method=lm, se = FALSE)

p.2 <- ggplot(moderator, aes(x = friends, y = happy, colour = country)) + 
    geom_point(size = 5) + geom_smooth(method=lm, se = FALSE) + 
    theme(legend.position = c(.2, .2))
grid.arrange(p.1, p.2, ncol=2)
```

[image: scatter plots of the two models]

It is clearer now what happened. The original coefficient was small because a second factor - country, moderated the relationship. When we considered it, the coefficient became larger.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are several correlations to think about. Suppose the model is

$$ y = x_1 \beta + x_2 \gamma + c + u$$

There can be a correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $c$ (for example suppose that $c$ is an omitted variable like ability).

**Disregarding $c$:** If $x_1,x_2$ are positively correlated and both are uncorrelated with the error term $u$ and with ability $c$, then we know that including $x_2$ compared to just regressing $y$ on $x_1$ will lead to a lower estimate of $\beta$, because before, $x_1$ was "sucking up" some of the variation that should have been attributed to $x_2$. However, if the two are *negatively* correlated, the opposite will be the case: this is because those with higher $x_1$ also have lower $x_2$, so the net effect on $y$ might be zero (if $\beta,\gamma$ are both positive).

**If $c$ is present and correlated** If both are correlated with $c$, then it's a question of the sign of this correlation and which is stronger.