# Cox Regression - IVs have different hazard ratios when modelled alone than all together

Tags: spss, cox-model

I'm currently running a Cox proportional hazards analysis on my data to look at outcomes for cancer survival. I'm looking at variables such as cancer type, martial status, gender etc. For some reason when I put in all of these variables together in the SPSS model, I get different hazard ratios than when I put them in separately. Does anyone who know is the reason for this? Am I missing something basic?

Comment: Do you mean that in models with each variable by itself, their coefficients are different than when all of them are used together?

Comment: Yes! For example, if I put in stuff like gender and martial status and different treatment together in the model, I'll get difference Exp(B)s and CIs as opposed to when I do them all separately in SPSS. Is there a reason for that/am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 1):

As with any type of regression, using multiple explanatory variables has several advantages over simple (single-var) models, besides being able to see them all together. Chief among these is the concept of control. When a single variable ($x$) is used, the coefficient is the effect (relationship, hazard ratio etc..) on the dependent variable ($y$). But relationships between two variables can be more complex than they appear. The relationship can be augmented by the existence of other variables ($x_i$), and this can be modeled and discovered using multiple covariates in the same model.

An a known, if silly example, a relationship between ice-cream sale and murder-rate is high (i.e. the coefficient is highly significant). This, however, is obviously bogus. There is a secondary variable that is in play here - weather. Hot weather increases both murders *and* ice-cream sales. In this case, weather is a **confounder** to the relationship between ice-cream sales and murder rates. For an overview of different types of such external influences ([confounders, mediators, moderators](https://significantlystatistical.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/confounders-mediators-moderators-and-covariates/)).

So, using extra variables in the model can often reveal the *true* relationships between a certain $x$ and a $y$. If, in a simple model, the coefficient of $x_1$ was $\beta_1$ and adding a second variable $x_2$ caused $\beta_1$ to increase in size (in absolute value), than the newly added $x_2$ is the reason for that change, and is likely *moderating* the relationship. If $\beta_1$ decreased (in absolute value), than $x_2$ is likely a confounder or a mediator.

As a more visual example of this, I'll use a part of an answer I gave to a [different question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251327/linear-regression-coefficients-increase-meaning/251400#251400):
Following are two linear regression models (same idea applies to Cox PH) - the first with one explanatory variable (number of friends) used to predict happiness:

```
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   15.105     14.697   1.028   0.3341  
friends        4.580      2.236   2.048   0.0747 .
```

The second is the same model, with an added country (japan or china):

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   -9.079     13.541  -0.670  0.52406   
friends       11.382      2.861   3.978  0.00534 **
country      -35.974     12.484  -2.881  0.02360 *
```

Note the change in $\beta_{friends}$ from 4.5 to 11.38. The addition of $x_{country}$ caused this. Why? Lets look at the graphs of the first and second models (first on the left):
[image: scatter plots of the two models]

When controlling for country, the effect ($\beta_{friends}$) grew.

At any rate, it is very common for coefficients to change when adding related variables to the model. Do not worry, your model is likely better off.