# Why correlation is not "transitive"?

Tags: correlation, dimensions

First let me explain what I mean by "transitive"
Suppose that the price of product A and the price of product B has a correlation of .5
Suppose also that the price of product B and product C has a correlation of .5

One might thing that if correlation(A,B) = .5 and correlation(B,C) = .5 then correlation(A,C) > 0, but with an intuitive example we can see why this is not the case:

Suppose that **A** is a fruit salad made of *papaya and banana*, suppose also that **B** is a fruit salad made of *banana and strawberry* and, finally, suppose that **C** is *strawberries and cream*. Clearly, when the price of banana goes up, both the price of **A and B** will go up; when the price of strawberry goes up the price of **B and C** will go up; but since **A** and **C** have no ingredients in common, their price isn't correlated.

My question is which statistical concept captures this intuitive idea. Is it the concept of dimensions?

**What do I mean by transitive?**
Let me define the binary operator X **corr?** Y as 1 if correlation(X,Y) != 0 and 0 otherwise, so:

- A corr? B = 1,
- B corr? C = 1, but
- A corr? C could be = 0

If corr? was transitive, then A corr? C = 1

Comment: Pictures like given [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/224823/3277) can help a lot in understanding correlations or regressions among 3 variables. Correlation is equal to the cosine of angle between variable vectors. So, you may take 3 pen beam and experiment with the 3 angles. You will find that as r_AB and r_BC go towards 0 r_AC gets more room to variate.

Comment: Exactly what "intuitive idea" are you asking about? You mentioned "transitive" and gave an example, but you did not actually define "transitive" and your example does not comport with the standard meaning of transitivity.  You have mentioned one specific statement about correlation and you have described one specific example of *causal linkages*, but if there's any underlying "idea" lurking here it doesn't seem to have been spelled out.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying you sense of "transitive"--but what exactly are you trying to ask in this question?  You seem to be requesting a "statistical concept," but what is it supposed to reflect?

Comment: @whuber I wrote the binary operator that gives a meaning to transitiveness of correlation. Muy intuitive idea is my example that informally shows correlation is not transitive

Comment: Right--we're all aware correlation is not transitive in this sense.  *But what is your question??*

Comment: @whuber perhaps I'm just looking for confirmation that in my example each fruit is a dimension (is that the correct concept to use?)

Comment: it's not clear, in part because your example is not really about correlation: it's about causality.  The two are completely different concepts.

Comment: @whuber ignoring my example, how could you proof that corr? is not transitive?

Comment: That has been done many, many times by many people on this site.  I most recently demonstrated it at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/256131/919.  You can find other demonstrations at http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=correlation+positive+definite+-spearman .

Comment: @whuber, when you wrote that my question was about causality I was like “I don’t even want to know what he means”. Some years have passed, I’ve read Judea’s book The Book of Why and now I get it. Your comment was right, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the correlations of $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $C$ are specified, then any value rho_AC such that the $3$ by $3$ matrix of correlations is positive semi-definite is a possible value of rho_AC.  Given the correlations of $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $C$, there will be a minimum and maximum such possible value of rho_AC.

Here is code in CVX under MATLAB which finds the minimum value of rho_AC.  The maximum such value is achieved with the identical program, but using maximize rather than minimize.  Although it is trivial to find the minimum and maximum possible values of rho_AC in this example, this approach still works quite well as the dimension of the problem increases.

```
% rho_AB and rho_BC are MATLAB variable values containing input correlations
cvx_begin
variable rho_AC
minimize(rho_AC)
% Next line constrains 3 by 3 correlation matrix to be positive semidefinite
[1 rho_AB rho_AC;rho_AB 1 rho_BC;rho_AC rho_BC 1] == semidefinite(3) 
cvx_end
```

Running this program for rho_AB -= 0.5 and rho_BC = 0.5, the minimum possible value for rho_AC is found to be -0.5 and the maximum possible value for rho_AC is found to be 1. Note that although this example is trivially solved without this fancy apparatus, this solution method readily and accurately (numerically stably) also works on higher dimensional problems and other more complicated variants.

Let the positive semi-definite cone be your guide to possible combinations of correlation. **The bottom line is that the 3 dimensional positive semi-definite cone does not satisfy transitivity for its 3rd parameter with respect to the other 2 parameters**.  Note that when rho_AB and rho_BC are both non-negative but unequal to each other, the maximum value of rho_AC will be less than $1$.

**Edit**: With regard to your edit after my answer: Consider, for example, your example of corr(A,B) = corr(B,C) = 0.5, which I analyzed above.  As shown above, per the mathematics of the positive semi-definite cone, $-0.5 \le$ corr(A,C) $\le 1$.  In particular, corr(A,C) might be equal to $0$ or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is less a different statistical concept than the amorphous nature of "correlation" itself. Dependence is usually defined as "not mathematically independent" even though we tend to conceptualize it the other way around.

In your example, you actually do not know if A & C are truly independent. For example, why did the price of papayas and bananas go up? If it was a drought in the area which also affected the strawberry crop or the grass fed to the cows who produced the milk for cream, there may be correlation.

There are many, many reasons why variables may not be independent. Dimensions as you say, and as [ttnpnhs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/3277/ttnphns) refers to in his comment is one way of showing it. Completely non-rigorously, it could be that the "planes" on which variables A & B and B & C interact are different enough so that the relationship between A & C, when forced into its plane, ends up with $P(A\cap C) = P(A)P(C)$ out of serendipity.

In a nutshell, I'd say that correlation is not transitive, because it it isn't a clean "function" or even a simple relationship. Rather, it is a shortcut definition comprising—or more accurately hiding—many possibilities. Therefore, outside of simple situations, it needs to be calculated manually for each pair of variables in question.

Answer (score 0):

[Transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) is a property of **binary relation**. Correlation (e.g, [Pearson correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)) is not a binary relation and therefore cannot be transitive.

One could define a binary relation using correlation by requiring correlation above a certain threshold.
Your example presents that even with this definition, correlation is not transitive. 
The correlation strength can decay over a chain of relation and go bellow the threshold.

Note that if the variables are a multiplication of each other in a non zero scalar, than you have transitivity.

Comment: One correlation being greater than another *is* a binary relation.  Thus this reply really doesn't seem to add any relevant information to the question.

Comment: In order to speak about the difference between correlation you should have two correlation and 3 variables. This is not a binary relation on the variables. As you wrote, it seems that the OP doesn't mean to the usual meaning of transitivity.

Comment: That comment belies some confusion. Let's check the definition given in the question. It describes $\mathcal{R}\subset V\times V$ on the set $V$ of all square-integrable random variables of nonzero variance (defined on some underlying probability space) *via* $$(X,Y)\in \mathcal{R}\text{ iff }\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y)\ne 0.$$ Because this is well-defined and is a subset of $V\times V$, it is a relation. (It obviously is symmetric and reflexive, btw.) By definition, it will be transitive exactly when $$(X,Y)\in\mathcal{R}\text{ and }(Y,Z)\in\mathcal{R}\text{ imply }(X,Z)\in\mathcal{R}.$$

Comment: Correct. It wasn't defined so in the version of the question I saw but added later.