# Variable relationship case: x1 is not correlated to y but x2 which is related to x1 is correlated to y

Tags: correlation, multicollinearity, importance, nonlinearity

I would like to know what is the specific term given to this case, or how is this justified in technical words:

x1 is not correlated to y but x2 which is correlated to x1 is correlated to y.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "related to"?

Comment: "correlated", sorry. When plotting a scatter plot between x1 and x2, correlation is noticed. When plotting x2 and y a correlation is also noticed. However, a weak correlation (or no obvious correlation) is seen when plotting x1 and y.

Comment: Have you looked at our threads on mutual correlations? Start with https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256440 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5747.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32169 is helpful for constructing examples of any possible sets of correlations.  For the terminology, search our site for "regression" along with "mediat*" or "confound*", or include both "significan*" and "not".